# How to escape | (Vertical Bar) character in Nginx configuration files?

Tags: regex, nginx, config, nginx-reverse-proxy

I know its possible to escape `|` in normal regular expressions by preceding a `\`. But it seems in nginx config files this is not working as expected:

```
# Don't use the cache only for these users: (user1 & user2)
if ($http_cookie ~* "wordpress_logged_in_.+=(user1|user2)\|.+") {
    set $no_cache 1;
    set $bypass_cache 1;
}
```

but in above code it seems nginx is not escaping `|` and its matching `.*` because `|` is considered as regex `OR` command.

Comment: The backslash escape mechanism works fine for me. As an alternative to backslash, you could try using a character class instead. Both `\|` and `[|]` worked in my tests.

Comment: @RichardSmith I tried your sugession but it wasn't helpful. My nginx version is latest nginx/1.22.0 from nginx-stable repository on centos7 server and its not working as expected even if I escape with `\|` or tried `[|]`. And if I use only `|` it always matches everything. You may have tested with some different parameters. I'm using `.` in production to bypass this problem but its not an answer to the question and its not a fix.